# PostgreSQL : Applying Pagination on UNION queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination, union

I've got 2 tables : Sale & Purchase.
I want to get a paginated Ledger report in a date range.

Query :

```
SELECT X.*
FROM
(
SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE date >= <> AND date <= <>
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Purchases WHERE date >= <> AND date <= <>
) X
ORDER BY
X.date
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 100
```

This query first fetches **ALL** the transactions in the date range and then applies LIMIT OFFSET on it; so there is no optimization on the SQL cost.

If I apply LIMIT OFFSET on the inner 2 select queries, it leads to data loss as the UNION is sorted by date finally.

Is there a way in which ALL data is not fetched; but only the paginated Sales & Purchases and then I get a merged ledger report ?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Obviously you can't apply OFFSET inside the UNIONed queries.  You would need to use just a LIMIT of 50+100 inside, and then apply the OFFSET and reapply a LIMIT outside the UNION as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing the UNION inside a CTE? (untested)

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE  ...
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM Purchases WHERE ...
)
SELECT * FROM x
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 100
```

Comment: Will this query have less cost than the one I mentioned in the question ? Won't the CTE perform the complete UNION  anyways and then apply LIMIT OFFSET? If both sales & purchases have 10 million rows each, which one is more optimized?

Comment: @SagarAgarwal no, it definitely won't perform well in such a large table. As a matter of fact, it is a pretty bad idea :D Perhaps a view / materialized view would be more appropriate in terms of performance, but that would depend on your use case.

Comment: @SagarAgarwal check this out: https://dbfiddle.uk/bDy0W1Lc let me know if it does not help you at all, so hat I can delete the answer. Regarding speed, it will mostly depend on the columns (and amount of records retrieved) in the `where` clause of the inner queries (cte).